# bash: cannot list backgrounded jobs when inside bash script

Tags: linux, macos, bash, job-control

I want to see the backgrounded jobs when inside a bash script.
Is this possible?
To illustrate I run the command /usr/bin/experiment here but end
up with no output.

```
$ cat /usr/bin/experiment
#!/bin/bash
echo $(jobs)

$ watch ls

[1]+  Stopped                 watch ls
$ /usr/bin/experiment

$
```

Comment: Does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script launches a new shell, which does not see the active jobs of the original shell.

If you run your script as follows:

```
source /usr/bin/experiment
```

you will get the output you are looking for